# Swift AVPlayer has no done button

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

Using iOS 8.4, I have created an AVPlayerViewController with and AVPlayer.  The video controls appear as expected and the video plays, but there is no "Done" button and xCode crashes whenever I try to lay one on the ViewController at the top of the view.  An example I saw:
[Video Playback](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_8_Video_Playback_using_AVPlayer_and_AVPlayerViewController)
clearly shows a "Done" button on the upper left of the screen.

Do AVPlayerViewController and AVPlayer support a "Done" button? Is it possible to add one?

The existing answer suggested by the comment included Objective-C code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No "Done" button on AVPlayerViewController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31036301/no-done-button-on-avplayerviewcontroller)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Done" button is present and working if doing this way:

```
    let playerVC = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerVC.player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mov")!)
    self.presentViewController(playerVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Swift 3**:

```
self.showDetailViewController(playerVC, sender: self) 
// presentViewController is deprecated
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was trying to nest the AVPlayerViewController as a child of another UIViewController and in that case, I get a run-time warning and the "Done" button doesn't display.

Comment: hi @rshev any chance you could help with this question on capturing video? thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704032/swift-video-records-at-one-size-but-renders-at-wrong-size

Comment: Is this the same as presenting the view modally per the storyboard?