# Done button click event in AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I want to play local video in AVPlayerViewController but did not find click event of Done button.

My video is able to play in AVPlayerViewController but I did not find next button , previous button and done button click event.

Answer (score 21):

I've done this to get `Done` button click event from `AVPlayerViewController`.
First of all, Create an extension of `Notification.Name` like bellow

```
extension Notification.Name {
static let kAVPlayerViewControllerDismissingNotification = Notification.Name.init("dismissing")
}
```

Now, Create an extension of `AVPlayerViewController` and override `viewWillDisappear` like bellow

```
// create an extension of AVPlayerViewController
extension AVPlayerViewController {
    // override 'viewWillDisappear'
    open override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        // now, check that this ViewController is dismissing
        if self.isBeingDismissed == false {
            return
        }

        // and then , post a simple notification and observe & handle it, where & when you need to.....
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .kAVPlayerViewControllerDismissingNotification, object: nil)
    }
}
```

THIS IS FOR ONLY BASIC FUNCTIONALITY THAT HANDLES DONE BUTTON'S EVENT.

happy coding...

Comment: How to handle when pause/forward/backward buttons are tapped?

Comment: @pkc456, in my opinion, you should create custom Player using AVPlayerLayer in UIViewController so you can easily handle those events.

Comment: Much better and safer.

Comment: Also a note to anyone who may use this, depending on the implementation you may be adding observers over and over, so don't forget to add them only once and remove them when appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. Its been few more hours since I was looking for solution.

Comment: very handy, concise and notification is really a good call for this case

Comment: Why not `if isBeingDismissed { //post-notification }` instead? I think it's more concise and better represents what you intend the code to accomplish.

Comment: Hi @TaylorM, thanks for suggestion...
Fortunately, I'm currently working on VideoEditor so, I'll give it a try and share updates.

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that you can start swiping to dismiss the player but then not dismiss it and the notification will be fired anyways. I would suggest posting the notification in `viewDidDisappear` instead.

Answer (score 18):

Officially there is no Done Button click event, a engineer from Apple said about it [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/20979).

As for my research, I found out that there is one but really indirect way to get an event if Done Button was clicked.

I found out that the only variable of AVPlayerViewController, which is changing when done button is clicked is `AVPlayerViewController.view.frame`. 
First of all view.frame is appearing in the center of the viewController.

If you present it with `animated : true` it goes to the bottom of viewController and the back to the center. When done is clicked it goes back to the bottom.

If you present it with `animated : false` there will be only 2 changes: frame will be at the center of viewController when you start to play video, and at the bottom, when Done is clicked.

So if you add observer to the `AVPlayerViewController.view.frame` in the callback to `present(PlayerViewController, animated : true)` you'll get only one call of the observer, right when done button is clicked and video view will be out of the screen.

In my case AVPlayerViewController was presented modally with animation. Code below worked for me:

**Swift 3.0**

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:Bundle.main.path(forResource: "MyVideo", ofType:"mp4")!)
    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL as URL)

    present(playerViewController, animated: false) { () -> Void in
        player.play()

        self.playerViewController.player = player
        self.playerViewController.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(UIViewController.view.frame), options: [.old, .new], context: nil)
    }}
    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?,
                           of object: Any?,
                           change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?,
                           context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)
{

    print(self.playerViewController.view.frame)
    //Player view is out of the screen and
    //You can do your custom actions
}
```

Also, I found out when you click Done, AVPlayerViewController is not dismissed and you can see it in `ParentViewController.presentedViewController`, so you can't add observer to this property

Comment: Thank you so much! @vmchar, save my whole day! Can not find the right answer anywhere but yours!

Comment: Worked perfectly :)

Comment: This will also be called if the user rotates their device, so it doesn't exactly serve as a "Done" button listener. And most certainly the device will be often rotated when playing a video.

Comment: @vmchar Is it possible in Objective-c?

Comment: @SamiulIslamSami it is. this approach is using KVC/KVO so you can rewrite it in objective-c.

Comment: what about if the user rotates the phone ? to watch the video in landscape

Answer (score 5):

Objective c version: (Based on vmchar answer)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
        AVPlayerViewController *AVPlayerVc = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
        if (AVPlayerVc) {
            [self presentViewController:AVPlayerVc animated:YES completion:^{
                [player play];
                AVPlayerVc.player = player;
                [AVPlayerVc addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"view.frame" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial) context:nil];
            }];

        }
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"view.frame"]) {
        CGRect newValue = [change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey]CGRectValue];
        CGFloat y = newValue.origin.y;
        if (y != 0) {
              NSLog(@"Video Closed");
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to reject your edit on https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24465963: I just happened to be editing the post line by line at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

This is a small improvement from the answer by  @vmchar:

We can use the .isBeingDismissed method to ensure that the AVPlayerViewController is being closed instead of analysing the frame.

```
...

let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:"video.mp4")
let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL as URL)

present(playerViewController!, animated: false) { () -> Void in
    player.play()

    self.playerViewController!.player = player
    self.playerViewController!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath:#keyPath(UIViewController.view.frame), options: [.old, .new], context: nil)
...
```

Then to observe the value

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?,
                           of object: Any?,
                           change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?,
                           context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)
{

    if (playerViewController!.isBeingDismissed) {  
     // Video was dismissed -> apply logic here
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest solution for me was to subclass `AVPlayerViewController` and add simple completion block to it.

```
class MYVideoController: AVPlayerViewController {

  typealias DissmissBlock = () -> Void
  var onDismiss: DissmissBlock?

  override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if isBeingDismissed {
      onDismiss?()
    }
  }
}
```

Usage

```
...
let avPlayerViewController = MYVideoController()
avPlayerViewController.onDismiss = { [weak self] in 
    print("dismiss")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround without having to subclass the `AVPlayerViewController`, which the documentation clearly states you should not (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller). It is not pretty, but it got the job done for me by giving me somewhere to run code when the `AVPlayerViewController` is dismissed.

```
AnyViewController: UIViewController, AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate {
    private let playerVC = AVPlayerViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        playerVC.delegate = self        
    }

    func playerViewController(_ playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController, willEndFullScreenPresentationWithAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        if playerViewController.isBeingDismissed {
            playerViewController.dismiss(animated: false) { [weak self] in
                self?.someDismissFunc()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is really messed up that there is no clean way of doing this as far as I can tell :(

Comment: Not sure if there are any downsides yet, but this seems to work and is the simplest solution so far. Hope others who are looking for a basic implementation for this use case sees it. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you can start dismissing the player by swiping but then swipe it back into place. This delegate is called anyways and isBeingDismissed is true so you end up thinking the player was dismissed when it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I found another trick (works with YoutubePlayer swift framework which plays videos in a webview, but you might be able to adapt it to other uses).

In my case, pressing the `Done` button and pressing the `Pause` button on the fullscreen video player both results in a `pause` event on the YoutubePlayer. However, as the video plays in a different window, I subclassed my application's main window and overrode the `becomeKey` and `resignKey` functions to store whether my window is the key window or not, like that:

```
class MyWindow:UIWindow {
    override func becomeKey() {
        Services.appData.myWindowIsKey = true
    }

    override func resignKey() {
        Services.appData.myWindowIsKey = false
    }
}
```

Once I have that, I can check whether my window is key when the video state goes to pause - when the `Done` button was pressed, my window **is** the key window and I can dismiss my video view controller, and in the `Pause` case my window **is not** the key window, so I do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are lots of ways to skin a cat. I needed to handle the 'Done' click event. In my case, I wanted to make sure I was able to hook into the event after the "X" was clicked and the AVPlayerViewController was COMPLETELY closed (dismissed).

Swift 4.0

```
protocol TableViewCellVideoPlayerViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func viewControllerDismissed()
}

class MyPlayerViewController: AVPlayerViewController {

    weak var navDelegate: TableViewCellVideoPlayerViewControllerDelegate?

    open override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        if self.isBeingDismissed {
            self.navDelegate?.viewControllerDismissed()
        }
    }
}

class TodayCell: UITableViewCell, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate,  TableViewCellVideoPlayerViewControllerDelegate {
    func viewControllerDismissed() {
        self.continueJourney()
    }
 }
```

Answer (score -6):

You can look into this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36389738/327565) and here is a [github's project](https://github.com/BeamApp/MusicPlayerViewController) for reference. You will have to use this :

```
 self.showsPlaybackControls = true
```

Please also have a look into [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/AVFoundationPiPPlayer/Introduction/Intro.html)