# detect AVPlayerViewController Done button click?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I'm writing Plugin for `AVPlayer` in ios. I need to know when user click on **Done** button in `AVPlayerViewController` ( I want to know when user close video) and I don't access to `AVPlayerViewController` object. I checked event and found only rate property in `AVPlayer` set to 0 but in pause situation also the rate set to 0 . how I figure out these two situations ? 
thanks all.

Comment: the [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41281453/4593553) work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Done button click event in AVPlayerViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38565412/done-button-click-event-in-avplayerviewcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

I met the problem when I was developing the player in windowed mode. It is [currently impossible](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15903) without tricks. Therefore, I used KVO to observe `contentOverlayView` which is actually a full-size view of `AVPlayerViewController`. Code is a bit complicated.  In the example below, `playerView` property is a view from xib/storyboard on the view controller (see attached).

```
#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

static NSString * const kBoundsProperty = @"bounds";
static void * kBoundsContext = &kBoundsContext;

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController;
// View for windowed mode.
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *playerView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Because in -viewDidLoad frame is unknown.
    [self loadPlayerView];
}

- (void)loadPlayerView {
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"];
    AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:videoURL];
    self.playerViewController.player = player;

    [player play];

    [self addChildViewController:self.playerViewController];
    [self.playerView addSubview:self.playerViewController.view];

    // MARK: I would recommend to use constraints instead of frame.
    self.playerViewController.view.frame = self.playerView.bounds;

    [self.playerViewController.contentOverlayView addObserver:self forKeyPath:kBoundsProperty options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:kBoundsContext];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (context == kBoundsContext) {
        CGRect oldBounds = [change[NSKeyValueChangeOldKey] CGRectValue];
        CGRect newBounds = [change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] CGRectValue];

        BOOL wasFullscreen = CGRectEqualToRect(oldBounds, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds);
        BOOL isFullscreen  = CGRectEqualToRect(newBounds, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds);
        if (isFullscreen && !wasFullscreen) {
            if (CGRectEqualToRect(oldBounds, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, newBounds.size.height, newBounds.size.width))) {
                NSLog(@"Rotated fullscreen");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Entered fullscreen");
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DidEnterInFullscreen" object:nil];
                });
            }
        } else if (!isFullscreen && wasFullscreen) {
            NSLog(@"Exited fullscreen");
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DidExitFromFullscreen" object:nil];
            });
        }
    }
}

@end
```

[image]