# Perform action when play button is tapped in AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I am using `AVPlayerViewController` to play video. When play button is tapped in `AVPlayerViewController` I need to perform some action. But I can't detect whether play button is tapped. Here is a picture for better understanding.[image]

Any assistance would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Officially there is not any  Done Button click event.

> What you could do is associate a UITapGestureRecognizer with the view
>   of the AVPlayerViewController, allowing the "menu" press type, and
>   cancelling touches in view. Your selector callback will then be
>   responsible for handling the pausing of playback and the dismissal of
>   the AVPlayerViewController, but it would also allow you to perform any
>   other cleanup required specific to your implementation.

Alternatively you can follow [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38565412/done-button-click-event-in-avplayerviewcontroller). Its smart workaround.