# Default fullscreen button action event in AVPlayerView Controller in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, objective-c-blocks, iphone-developer-program

I want to retrieve action event of default fullscreen button in `AVPlayerViewController`. How can i get that button action event? As i want to do edit in that action method. The Fullscreen button will displayed when we do `playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = YES;` in `AVPLayerViewController`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38565412/done-button-click-event-in-avplayerviewcontroller

Comment: Brother above link is not suitable for my question. I am asking for default fulscreen icon  button not Done button in AVPlayerViewController.