# How to hide done button in AVPlayerViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

At time of fullscreen in AVPlayerViewController at the top of that it display done button, I want to hide or remove that done button.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31036301/no-done-button-on-avplayerviewcontroller

Comment: Karthik this is link not appropriate for my question.....
If you know then can you please suggest me with code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: oh, see this may be helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43062870/add-custom-controls-to-avplayer-in-swift